# Issues with For Loop in VB

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

```
For i = 1 To 5
    If i = 0 Then
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        LabelEvens.Text = i
        i = i + 1
    Else
        LabelOdds.Text = i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next i
```

I'm making a program in VB where I have to use a for loop to sort between 2 numbers(loop limit 1 and 2) and find if they are even or odd, Then output the results to 2 labels. This loop makes sense to me, but for example when I put in 1 and 4 all it outputs is a 5 in the odd label. I guess my question is can anyone see the issue with my loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add 1 to your loop variable `i` manually, the `for` loop itself does that for you behind the scenes:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        LabelEvens.Text = i
    Else
        LabelOdds.Text = i
    End If
Next i
```

You'll noticed I've also removed the `If i = 0` bit since `i` can never be zero within that loop. It ranges from one to five inclusive.

One other thing you'll need to do is to *append* the value to your text box. What you have at the moment is a replacement so that it'll only be set to the last value processed. Something like this should suffice:

```
' Initialise to empty strings '

LabelEvens.Text = ""
LabelOdds.Text = ""

' Append the values '

For i = 1 To 5
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        LabelEvens.Text = LabelEvens.Text & "," & CStr(i)
    Else
        LabelOdds.Text = LabelOdds.Text & "," & CStr(i)
    End If
Next i

' Remove initial comma from both '

LabelEvens.Text = Mid(LabelEvens.Text,2)
LabelOdds.Text = Mid(LabelOdds.Text,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some issues in your code:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    If i = 0 Then                 <-- 'I' will never be 0 since you start from 1
        i = i + 1                 <-- Don't manually increment since you are using a for
    ElseIf i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        LabelEvens.Text = i
        i = i + 1                 <-- Don't manually increment since you are using a for
    Else
        LabelOdds.Text = i
        i = i + 1                 <-- Don't manually increment since you are using a for
    End If
Next i
```

Another issue you have is that if you have more than one odd number in the for range (say in a range of 1 to 10) you will only get the last number. What do you want to do in this case? Concatenate all odd numbers in a string or stop after the first one is found? Do you really need a FOR loop at all?

Answer (score 0):

you can Also state

```
LabelEvens.Text=""  'Clear contents of the label before assigning new values
LabelOdds.Text=""
   For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            LabelEvens.Text = LabelEvens.Text & i
        Else
            LabelOdds.Text = LabelOdds.Text & i
        End If
   Next
```

From Above you can replace '&' with  '+' if you want the Total.